# Select a range of a x keys from array php

Tags: php

How do i echo out a range from array $database for example data2 to data3?.

```
$database= array ("data1","data2","data3","data4");
```

Array_slice in this case will slove my problem.

```
$result = array_slice($database, 1, 2);
var_dump($result);
```

will output

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'data2' (length=5)
1 => string 'data3' (length=5)
```

Comment: And how you define that range ?

Comment: Do an 'If' inside you loop

Comment: `foreach (array_slice($database, 1, 2) as $data) { ... }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How 'foreach' actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the range `array_slice` is what you will need.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

In your scenario:

```
$database = array("data1","data2","data3","data4");
$result = array_slice($database, 1, 2);
var_dump($result);
```

If you didn't know the range, you can find it using `array_search`

https://www.php.net/array_search

In your scenario:

```
$database = array("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6","data7","data8","data9");
$startKey = "data2";
$endKey = "data6";

$startRange = array_search($startKey, $database);
$endRange = array_search($endKey, $database);
$result = array_slice($database, $startRange, $endRange - $startRange + 1);
var_dump($result);
```

Careful though, if you have more than one of the same value, it will use the first one it finds in the array.

W

Comment: Clean and easy to understand thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
$database= array ("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6");

$start = 'data2';
$end = 'data4';
$started = false;
foreach ($database as $key=>$data){
    if ($data == $start) {
        $started = true;
    }
    if ($started == true) {
        echo $data;
    }
    if ($data == $end) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's a link to ideone: http://ideone.com/vxzMMq

Comment: Thanks this help alot, im kinda new into arrays, i allways prefered ifs but when project scales up its impossible to achive it with a fair ammout of code.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a counter

```
$database= array("data1","data2","data3","data4");
$i=0;

foreach ($database as $key=>$data){
$i++;
if ($i!=1 && $i!=4)
echo $data;

}
```

It's a kludge, but it works :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if condition inside for each for checking the correct indices:

```
$database= array ("data1","data2","data3","data4");
$i=0;
foreach ($database as $key=>$data){
if($i>0 && $i<3)
 {
  echo $data;
 }
 $i++;
}
```